# sonar 5.2 NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

My environment is the following:

```
http://localhost:9000/sonar/api/server/version :: 5.2
java,sonar-java-plugin-3.7.jar|07dba2b9cad37584d82522414b2dccd0
scmgit,sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0.jar|e1d9d8e1d3524f9f0f69017e6dbead02
scmsvn,sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar|188d526ad86ec7f2dc7de694bf5f1851

printenv | grep MAVEN<BR>
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

I launch the command:

`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.verbose=true`

and it fails as reported here below.

If I insert the file `MyFileName.java` (ref. backtrace) in the SonarQube Global Source File Exclusions, then the process goes ahead, up to a next file (likely to a next file that needs to be traced because it's affected by some issue) and it fails again with the same symptoms.

There's no specific trace in the `sonar.log` file.

Same results with:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar -Dsonar.verbose=true
```

The main project I'm trying to analyse is very wide and the "module" that is failing is the 103rd one; this is only to say that there are several modules already processed in the previous stages without any sonar failures.

Any suggestions on how I could investigate this issue?

Backtrace:

```
....
[INFO] -------------  Scan My103thModule
[INFO] Language is forced to java
[INFO] Base dir: /bla/bla/bla
[INFO] Working dir: /bla/bla/bla/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 1 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found.
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found.
[INFO] JaCoCoOverallSensor: JaCoCo reports not found.
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[....] 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[....]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project mlwc.project: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : ' ..../MyFileName.java': NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project mlwc.project: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : ' ..../MyFileName.java'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : ' ..../MyFileName.java'
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '..../MyFileName.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:105)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:77)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:123)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:90)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:275)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:99)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.batch.source.SymbolizableBuilder.loadPerspective(SymbolizableBuilder.java:46)
    at org.sonar.batch.source.SymbolizableBuilder.loadPerspective(SymbolizableBuilder.java:32)
    at org.sonar.batch.deprecated.perspectives.BatchPerspectives.as(BatchPerspectives.java:63)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.symbolizableFor(SonarComponents.java:111)
    at org.sonar.java.model.InternalVisitorsBridge.createSonarSymbolTable(InternalVisitorsBridge.java:170)
    at org.sonar.java.model.InternalVisitorsBridge.visitFile(InternalVisitorsBridge.java:104)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:97)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Would you be able to test Sonarqube 5.2 with sonar-java-plugin-3.6 to see if this issue is due to version 3.7 of the java plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but we already performed exactly the tentative you're suggesting. Also with Sonar Java Plugin 3.6 the output is the same: failure with same symptoms.

Comment: Would you be able to share the source code of the file where the failure is happening ?

Comment: Hi, I installed again the system from scratch and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and found that upgrading (from 5.2) to SonarQube 5.3 resolved it. This suggests that the issue is related to a bug with 5.2 however I have not been able to track down the specific fix. I'll update this answer with a link to the Jira if I find it

Comment: Hello, I am also getting the NPE but with SonarQube 5.6.2, any idea to resolve it?